# Distributed transactions - why do we save tranlogs to file system?

Tags: database, oracle, transactions, distributed-transactions, 2phase-commit

All transaction managers (Atomikos, Bitronix, IBM WebSphere TM etc) save some "transaction logs" into 'tranlogs' folder to file system.

When something terrible happens and server gets down sometimes tranlogs become broken. 
They require some manual recovery procedure.

I've been told that by simply clearing broken tranlogs folder I risk to have an inconsistent state of resources that participated in transactions.

As a "dumb" developer I feel more comfortable with simple concepts. I *want to think* that distributed transaction management *should* be alike the regular transaction management:

1. If something went wrong at any party (network, app error, timeout) - I expect the whole multi-resource transaction not to be committed in any part of it. All leftovers should be cleaned up sooner or later automatically.
2. If transaction managers fails (file system fault, power supply fault) - I expect all the transactions under this TM to be rollbacked (apparently, at DB timeout level).
3. File storage for tranlogs is optional if I don't want to have any automatic TX recovery (whatever it would mean).

**Questions**

Why can't I think like this? What's so complicated about 2PC?

What are the exact risks when I clear broken tranlogs?

If I am wrong and I really need all the mess with 2PC file system state. Don't you feel sick about the fact that TX manager can actually break storage state in an easy and ugly manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I was first confronted with 2 phase commit in real life in 1994 (initially on a larger Oracle7 environment), I had a similar initial reaction. What a bloody shame that it is not generally possible to make it simple. But looking back at algorithm books of university, it become clear that there is no general solution for 2PC.

See for instance [how to come to consensus in a distributed environment](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/content/consensus.html)

Of course, there are many specific cases where a 2PC commit of a transaction can be resolved more easy to either complete or roll back completely and with less impact. But the general problem stays and can not be solved.

In this case, a transaction manager has to decide at some time what to do; a transaction can not remain open forever. Therefor, as an ultimate solution they will always need to have go back to their own transaction logs, since one or more of the other parties may not be able to reliably communicate status now and in the near future. Some transaction managers might be more advanced and know how to resolve some cases more easily, but the need for an ultimate fallback stays.

I am sorry for you. Fixing it generally seems to be identical to "Falsity implies anything" in binary logic.

## Summarizing

On `Why can't I think like this?` and `What's so complicated about 2PC`: See above. This algorithmetic problem can't be solved universally.

On `What are the exact risks when I clear broken tranlogs?`: the transaction manager has some database backing it. Deleting translogs is the same problem in general relational database software; you loose information on the transactions in process. Some db platforms can still have somewhat or largely integer files. For background and some database theory, [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_log).

On `Don't you feel sick about the fact that TX manager can actually break storage state in an easy and ugly manner?`: yes, sometimes when I have to get a lot of work done by the team, I really hate it. But well, it keeps me having a job :-)

## Addition: to 2PC or not

From your addition I understand that you are thinking whether or not to include 2PC in your projects.

In my opinion, your mileage may vary. Our company has as policy for 2PC: avoid it whenever possible. However, in some environments and especially with legacy systems and complex environments such a found in banking you can not work around it. The customer requires it and they may be not willing to allow you to perform a major change in other infrastructural components.

When you must do 2PC: do it well. I like a clean architecture of the software and infrastructure, and something that is so simple that even 5 years from now it is clear how it works.

For all other cases, we stay away from two phase commit. We have our own framework (Invantive Producer) from client, to application server to database backend. In this framework we have chosen  to sacrifice elements of ACID when normally working in a distributed environment. The application developer must take care himself of for instance atomicity. Often that is possible with little effort or even doesn't require thinking about. For instance, all software must be safe for restart. Even with atomicity of transactions this requires some thinking to do it well in a massive multi user environment (for instance locking issues).

In general this stupid approach is very easy to understand and maintain. In cases where we have been required to do two phase commit, we have been able to just replace some plug-ins on the framework and make some changes to client-side code.

So my advice would be:

- Try to avoid 2PC.
- But encapsulate your transaction logic nicely.
- Allowing to do 2PC without a complete rebuild, but only changing things where needed.

I hope this helps you. If you can tell me more about your typical environments (size in #tables, size in GB persistent data, size in #concurrent users, typical transaction mgmt software and platform) may be i can make some additions or improvements.

## Addition: Email and avoiding message loss in 2PC

Regarding whether suggesting DB combining with JMS: No, combining DB with JMS is normally of little use; it will itself already have some db, therefor the original question on transaction logs.

Regarding your business case: I understand that per event an email is sent from a template and that the outgoing mail is registered as an event in the database.

This is a hard nut to crack; I've been enjoying doing security audits and one of the easiest security issues to score was checking use of email.

Email - besides not being confidential and tampersafe in most situations like a postcard - has no guarantees for delivery and/or reading without additional measures. For instance, even when email is delivered directly between your mail transfer agent and the recipient, data loss can occur without the transaction monitor being informed. That even gets worse when multiple hops are involved. For instance, each MTA has it's own queueing mechanism on which a "bomb can be dropped" leading to data loss. But you can also think of spam measures, bad configuration, mail loops, pressing delete file by accident, etc. Even when you can register the sending of the email without any loss of transaction information using 2PC, this gives absolutely no clue on whether the email will arrive at all or even make it across the first hop.

The company I work for sells a large software package for project-driven businesses. This package has an integrated queueing mechanism, which also handles email events. Typically combined in most implementation with Exchange nowadays. A few months we've had a nice problem: transaction started, opened mail channel, mail delivered to Exchange as MTA, register that mail was handled... transaction aborted, since Oracle tablespace full. On the next run, the mail was delivered again to Exchange, again abort, etc. The algorithm has been enhanced now, but from this simple example you can see that you need all endpoints to cooperate in your 2PC, even when some of the endpoints are far away in an organisation receiving and displaying your email.

If you need measures to ensure that an email is delivered or read, you will need to supplement it by additional measures. Please pick one of application controls, user controls and process controls from literature.

Comment: My specific reason is simple. Whether or not should I use 2PC in my future software projects? As far as I understand, we can "trade" 2PC for a custom mechanism that assures data integrity. This trade off is not simple, as custom code is weak for bugs, and 2PC is weak for its natural "flaw".

Comment: Guido, thank you very much for the valuable addition. The typical picture for me would be to wire JMS + DB together. For example, JMS takes the heavy load of incoming events into a queue. Some processor on the other end of the queue would handle events using some database (storing/routing etc).

Comment: You are welcome. I don't understand the typical picture; using JMS backup by DB plus some smarter processor on contents in the DB is still typical routing/forwarding/orchestration (JMS++ so to say). What type of business applications are you thinking of? What volume of events per second and for instance 95% acceptable turn-around time per event?

Comment: Am I right that you propose to backup JMS implementation with the same DB, to avoid distributed transactions? This may be a solutuon for some cases, but more often JMS is a standalone server like WebSphere MQ or ActiveMQ, with its own transactions. This is very common in systems integration and other distributed systems that have JMS as backbone.

Comment: In my case, i have multiple instances of notification module listening to some queue. When a message comes, one of them will look up an email template in the DB, send an email, and update something in DB after. So I have to use 2PC to wire JMS and DB so that no message is lost.

Comment: The question is initiated by the fact I feel unhappy about the fogginess of the matter of 2PC. And I still don't know what I lose if I once have to delete the broken tranlogs folder.

Comment: Added info on email and 2PC to answer. Is your question answered or is there something I can help you with (will be off next days)

Comment: The only reason I don't grant the bounty to your answer right away is that the 3rd question asked initially is still not answered explicitly. I would be very pleased to give you the bounty you deserve, could you please update the answer to address the exact question?

Comment: Hmm, ok. To help have some background, but it is general computing theory issue. For specific products the actuals can vary, but even a transaction manager needs some storage in a database to allow him to recover after a crash.